# Forloop error codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, for-loop, controller

I have written a code for sending emails to multiple emailaddress in the controller, but I guess I have written it wrong, and I am not sure if I wrote the clear email in the write part of the forloop as well. Sorry this might be a easy question but I am some what new in this field.

```
public function sendEmailforUnpaidInvoiceFromDB() {
    //fetch tha data from the database 
    $this->load->model('invoice_page');
    $foo = $this->invoice_page->getInvoicesForNotification();
    $result = json_decode(json_encode($foo[0]), true);
    foreach ($foo as $result){
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from('helloworld@hello.com', 'HELLO');
    $this->email->to($result['Email']);
    $this->email->subject('Pay Payments');
    //$msg = $this->load->view('mypayment_view', '', true);
    $this->email->message('your due date is '.$result['duedate']);  
    $returnvalue = $this->email->send();


    if(!$returnvalue) {
       alert("email failed to send");
    } else {
     // $uptArray = array('customer_notified_dt' => NOW());
      //$this -> db -> update('invoice', $uptArray);
       }
    $this->email->clear(TRUE);   
    }
}
```

I am getting 2 arrays from the model, including Email and duedate.
Error picture [image: error using the url directly], and [image: error using the button I placed]

Comment: Why do you think it works wrong? Do you get any error messages? If yes, post those here.

Comment: @ArthurGevorkyan I added error pictures

Comment: Now you have better chances to find help on your problem! Good luck, man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here,

```
$result = json_decode(json_encode($foo[0]), true);
foreach ($foo as $result){
                 ^// overwriting previous variable
```

If `$result` is object, access using `->`

```
 $result->email;
```

If its an array

```
 $result['email'];
```

**EDIT**

you are getting only one row because,

```
$result = json_decode(json_encode($foo[0]), true);
                                       ^
```

you are considering only first index., remove that `0` as index.

Comment: rename the variable as `$result1`.

Comment: I did rename the variable , but If I use $result->email it only works for the first row coming from database, doesnt work for the second row with new email address info

Comment: Where us you email's present?? In foo or $result??

Comment: Foo gets the email and duedate , and result changes it to json decode, so using $result would work

Comment: mistake is here `$result = json_decode(json_encode($foo[0]), true);` you are taking only `$foo[0]`. so its working only once.

Comment: So should I only write ($foo)

Comment: Yea it was, and can you please edit your answer about the $foo, so someone else will understand in the future, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to read objects as arrays, like the error says. Try to replace these:

```
$this->email->to($result['Email']);
$this->email->message('your due date is '.$result['duedate'])
```

With these:

```
$this->email->to($result->Email);
$this->email->message('your due date is '.$result->duedate);
```

Comment: But It does not work when I have multiple rows coming from the database, only works for the first one @J_vdv

Comment: Do a print_r of $result and see what's in there. The data is fetched in the wrong way then.

Comment: Like Niranjan N Raju said, change $foo[0] to $foo in your json_decode. $foo[0] only gets the first index of your object.

Comment: Yea I just fixed it, and thanks! I am not sure if I can give tick to both of yours and Niranjan answers, since both of them helped.

Comment: You can't, but that's okay. Niranjan was the one who suggested that first. I just put you in the right direction. Just remember to always use print_r($variable); for this kind of stuff. Then you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this One:

```
public function sendEmailforUnpaidInvoiceFromDB() {
        //fetch tha data from the database 
        $this->load->model('invoice_page');
        $foo = $this->invoice_page->getInvoicesForNotification();

        foreach ($foo as $result){
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->from('helloworld@hello.com', 'HELLO');
        $this->email->to($result->Email);
        $this->email->subject('Pay Payments');
        //$msg = $this->load->view('mypayment_view', '', true);
        $this->email->message('your due date is '.$result->duedate);  
        $returnvalue = $this->email->send();


        if(!$returnvalue) {
           alert("email failed to send");
        } else {
         // $uptArray = array('customer_notified_dt' => NOW());
          //$this -> db -> update('invoice', $uptArray);
           }
        $this->email->clear(TRUE);   
        }
    }
```